# Set datatypes of React table column values before exporting to csv

Tags: reactjs, types, export-to-csv, react-table

I am creating a table in react and want to specify each columns datatype so that if the data is being exported the values are still in the right way. Currently, the table data is being displayed correct but if I export to csv, the all my values are surrounded by quotation marks, indicating strings.
How can I specify that?

```
import React from "react";
import { useTable } from "react-table";
import { CSVLink } from "react-csv";
import "./employee.css";


const columns = [
    { Header: "Last Name", accessor: "lastName"},
    { Header: "First Name", accessor: "firstName"},
    { Header: "Day 30 Amount", accessor: "day30"},
    { Header: "Day 60 Amount", accessor: "day60"},
    { Header: "Day 90 Amount", accessor: "day90"},
    { Header: "Day 120 Amount", accessor: "day120"},
    { Header: "Day 150 Amount", accessor: "day150"},
    { Header: "Day 210+ Amount", accessor: "day210"},
    { Header: "Rolling 12 Month Times Fee Charged", accessor: "rolling12months"},
    { Header: "Name", accessor: "name"},
];


function Employee({employeeData}) {

    const data1 = JSON.stringify(employeeData)
    const data = JSON.parse(data1);

  // Calling react table hook
    const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } =
    useTable({ columns, data });

  //Contains the column headers and table data in the required format for CSV
  const csvData = [
    ["Last Name", "First Name", "Day 30 Amount", "Day 60 Amount", "Day 90 Amount", "Day 120 Amount", "Day 150 Amount", "Day 210+ Amount", "Rolling 12 Month Times Fee Charged", "Name"],
    ...data.map(({ lastName, firstName, day30, day60, day120, day150, day210, rolling12months, name }) => [
        lastName,
      firstName,
        day30,
        day60,
        day120,
        day150,
        day210,
        rolling12months,
      name
    ]),
  ];


  return (
   // ...
      <CSVLink className="downloadbtn" filename="AmexDataProcessed.csv" data={csvData}>
        Export to CSV
      </CSVLink>
// ...
)
```